# Libgdx/ Java cameras for multiple players?

Tags: java, server, libgdx

I am trying to make a little multiplayer rpg game.

It all worked fine, until I implemented cameras for each player.

Now I got the problem, that if one player joines, he can't walk alone. It seems that he is stuck on the Client players cam. I have created a camera for each of them. Did I miss something?

Here's my "Main" class

```
public class LauncherScreen implements Screen{

//-----------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------idle Animation----------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------

Texture texture;

AnimatedSprite animationForMultiplayer;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;   
Player mySelf;
OrthographicCamera playerCam;
OrthographicCamera mpPlayerCam;

static Client client = new Client();



Launcher launcher = new Launcher();


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    launcher.update();

    for(MPPlayer mpPlayer : launcher.getPlayersValue()){   

        //System.out.println("mpPlayerXandY : "+mpPlayer.state);

        animationForMultiplayer.setState(mpPlayer.state);

        animationForMultiplayer.createAnimation();

        mpPlayerCam.update();

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mpPlayerCam.combined);
        spriteBatch.begin();                
        spriteBatch.draw(animationForMultiplayer.convertAnimationTOframes(), mpPlayer.x, mpPlayer.y,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/25,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);     // #6
        spriteBatch.end();

        mpPlayerCam.position.set(mpPlayer.x,mpPlayer.y,0);


        System.out.println("mpPlayer : "+mpPlayer.x+" "+mpPlayer.y);


    }


    mySelf.update();
    mySelf.draw(launcher.getPlayerX(), launcher.getPlayerY(), playerCam);

    //System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());


    System.out.println("player : "+launcher.getPlayerX()+" "+launcher.getPlayerY());


}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //super.pause();

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //super.resume();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //super.dispose();

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("EnemyAnimations/BugIdleStand.png"));
    animationForMultiplayer = new AnimatedSprite();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();              
    mySelf = new Player();

    mySelf.doSetup();



    playerCam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    playerCam.setToOrtho(false);
    playerCam.position.set(mySelf.getX(), mySelf.getY(), 0);

    mpPlayerCam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    mpPlayerCam.setToOrtho(false);
    mpPlayerCam.position.set(0, 0, 0);

}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And here's the "Main" player update

```
    public void draw(float f, float g, OrthographicCamera camera){

    position.x = f;
    position.y = g;

    //System.out.println("In beforeSetState : "+currentState);
    animatedSprite.setState(state);
    //System.out.println("In after : "+currentState);
    animatedSprite.createAnimation();

    camera.position.set(f,g,0);
    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(animatedSprite.convertAnimationTOframes(),f,g, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/25,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);             // #17
    batch.end();
    //batch.setProjectionMatrix(null);




    //System.out.println(currentState);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for it, didnt knew that it was so easy ^^ heres my updated code

```
public class LauncherScreen implements Screen{

//-----------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------idle Animation----------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------

Texture texture;

AnimatedSprite animationForMultiplayer;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;   
Player mySelf;

OrthographicCamera playerCam;
OrthographicCamera mpPlayerCam;
OrthographicCamera camera;

ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

static Client client = new Client();
Launcher launcher = new Launcher();


int[][] map = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    launcher.update();


    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){


        for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){

            if(map[i][j] == 1){

                 shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

                 shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
                 shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
                 shapeRenderer.rect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
                 shapeRenderer.end();

            }

        }

    }



    for(MPPlayer mpPlayer : launcher.getPlayersValue()){   

        //System.out.println("mpPlayerXandY : "+mpPlayer.state);

        animationForMultiplayer.setState(mpPlayer.state);

        animationForMultiplayer.createAnimation();

        //mpPlayerCam.update();

        //spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mpPlayerCam.combined);        

        camera.position.set(mpPlayer.x,mpPlayer.y,0);


        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        spriteBatch.begin();                
        spriteBatch.draw(animationForMultiplayer.convertAnimationTOframes(), mpPlayer.x, mpPlayer.y,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/25,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);     // #6
        spriteBatch.end();

        //mpPlayerCam.position.set(mpPlayer.x,mpPlayer.y,0);


        System.out.println("mpPlayer : "+mpPlayer.x+" "+mpPlayer.y);


    }


    mySelf.update();
    mySelf.draw(launcher.getPlayerX(), launcher.getPlayerY(), camera);

    //System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());

    camera.update();

    System.out.println("player : "+launcher.getPlayerX()+" "+launcher.getPlayerY());


}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //super.pause();

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //super.resume();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //super.dispose();

}


@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("EnemyAnimations/BugIdleStand.png"));
    animationForMultiplayer = new AnimatedSprite();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();              
    mySelf = new Player();

    mySelf.doSetup();



    playerCam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    playerCam.setToOrtho(false);
    playerCam.position.set(mySelf.getX(), mySelf.getY(), 0);

    mpPlayerCam = new OrthographicCamera(0,0);
    mpPlayerCam.setToOrtho(false);


    camera = new OrthographicCamera(0, 0);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);



    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}






 }
```